# Define global textbox (or other control) width in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, layout

I'd like to be able to maintain the width of controls globally throughout my WPF application.

Previously in winforms world I'd override onload in a base form and iterate through all controls and containers and determine the type of controls and set the dimensions accordingly.

I guess I could do the same in WPF but is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a [Style](http://wpftutorial.net/Styles.html) for TextBox at the highest level in your Visual Hierarchy.

Comment: Perfect, thank you.
I knew there was something (major) I was missing :)

Answer (score 1):

Define TextBox style in the resource dictionary and put a setter to set the desired width

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type TextBox}" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="200" />
      ..........
</Style>
```